# Default value in remote methods in loopback framework

Tags: node.js, database, express, loopbackjs

After writing application logic in particular model.js file I have defined remote method for that particular model as I want to expose that api and I want to accept some arguments in which one of the argument is `object` type and I want to give default value to that argument

I have done like this

```
     {
        arg: 'whereConditionFilter',
        type: 'object',
        default: {},
        required: true
      },
```

But I am confused is this the correct way to do this thing.

Comment: Default value that will be used to populate loopback-explorer input fields and swagger documentation. Note: This value will not be passed into remote methods function if argument is not present.

Answer (score 1):

You can use beforeRemote hook for that.

```js
Model.beforeRemote( 'yourCustomRemoteMethod', function( ctx, instance, next) { 
let whereConditionFilter = ctx.req.params.whereConditionFilter; 
/*Modify your whereConditionFilter here and resign it*/
})
```